# Can you help me decipher this cryptography?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

i've been trying to work out the result for a while but I have'nt worked it out yet.

It says:
Sometimes hackers appear in the most unlikely of places. Our team recently uncovered a hacker who was running a coffee shop as a cover for his secret identity. He hacked the cash register to show secret messages to particular customers. We knew it used some kind of cipher to hide them. Take a look at the example receipt below - can you find the hidden message?
                                 ***

> ```
>                             Crypto Coffee
>                        Brew Street, Copenhagen
>    Qu.      Reference            Name       Amount
>    2        rcuuyqtfk          Americano    EUR 4.00
>    3        dphulfdqr          Croissant    EUR 2.25
>                                                     Total: EUR 6.25
> ```

I know it has something to do with the reference but I just can't decipher it. Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: The question is off-topic: Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this some kind of homework?
If yes I'm kind of reluctant to give the solution, but since it likely is supposed to be decryptable, take a look into some easy ciphers.
Try Cesar's cipher first. If you take the numbers on the receipt into account, it's even easier...

Comment: If it is just a reference it could just be a hash which is not decryptable.

Comment: There has been a series of these puzzles on SO recently.  I'm not really sure what satisfaction comes from having someone solve a puzzle, though.